# Warnings with if statements

Tags: r

When i'm trying to run an if and else if statements in R

[image]

I'm getting these warnings, so shouldn't we use if statements on dataframes and their columns at all? are  they used only for single vectors?

[image]

Can someone please help

Comment: Please don't share data/code as images, share them as text instead. Yes `if`/`else` are used only for scalars for vectors use `ifelse`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the previous comment, `ifelse` works with vectors.

This should work:

```
logik <- mtcars

ifelse(logik$mpg < 10, print("less than 10"), 
     ifelse(logik$mpg > 10 & logik$mpg < 20, "Between 10 and 20", "Greater than 20"))
```